# Determine $f(z)$ if $f(z)$ is an entire function with the following property

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Determine $f(z)$ if $f(z)$ is an entire function such that

$|f(z) + e^z| > |e^z|$  $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$

I wanted to use the extended/general Liouville theorem to determine $f(z)$, but I'm not sure how to get started.

Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $f(z)+e^z\ne 0$ by the first inequality. It follows that $e^z/(f(z)+e^z)$ is entire, and bounded above. You should be able to conclude from that.

Comment: Ah ! I see, after that we just call $g(z) = \frac{e^z}{f(z) + e^z}$ and hit  $g(z)$ with Liouville theorem to derive at $f(z)$. Thank you !